# How to upgrade Chrome webdriver in NoraUi?

Tags: noraui

What is the exact process in order to upgrade the webdriver for a given browser in NoraUI?

An outdated webdrivers causes the following error:

`org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:  session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80 Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- check your Chrome version
- kill all webdriver process
- remove your local webdriver
- edit pom.xml

  - search your version on https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
  - copy version in `profile(preIC) > build > plugins > plugin(download-maven-plugin) >      executions > execution(download-googlechrome-webdriverxxxx) > configuration > url`
  - search your ETag on https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.39/
  - copy ETag in `profile(preIC) > build > plugins > plugin(download-maven-plugin) > executions > execution(download-googlechrome-webdriverxxxx) > configuration > md5`
- run robot